# How to save user input, update array, and render updated array on button press

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react web application that I am developing. The code from the component in question renders semesters of a degree 2 at a time. The user is able to see each class in a semester. There are buttons to go to the next two semesters as well as the previous two semesters. There is also a button to view all semesters at once. This is where my problem lies. In the 2 semester view the user has the option to edit any class that contains 'Elective' or 'Cognate'. There is also a save button under each semester to manage the changes made (the handleSave function does nothing yet). When I make a change in the 2 semester view and then click on the button to display all semesters, my changes are not being reflected.

I have tried creating state variables that are a copy of the splitArray array and then updating that through the handleSave function but it didnt work. I also know that in the 2 semester view a new 'items' array is created every time out of the splitArray array. The items[1] is the name of the class to be edited. So i have no idea how to create a copy of the splitArray array with the edited items[1] being in the correct place. The first paragraph (following the showAll? is rendered when the display all button is pressed). The second paragraph is the 2 semester view in which the user is able to make edits.

```
{showAll
              ? splitArray.map((item, index) => (
                  <li key={index} style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: '10px' }}>
                    <p>Semester {index + 1}:</p>
                    <div className="semester-lines">
                      <div>
                        <p style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                          {item
                            .replace(/],/g, ']<br/>')
                            .replace(/[[\]]/g, '')
                            .split('<br/>')
                            .map((line, index) => {
                              const items = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
                              
                              return (
                                <div key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                                  <span style={{ padding: '5px', margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)' }}>
                                    {items[0]}
                                  </span>
                                  <span style={{ padding: '5px',maxWidth: '300px' ,margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)' }}>
                                    {items[1]}
                                  </span>
                                  <span style={{ padding: '5px', margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
                                    {items[2]}
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                              );
                            })}
                        </p>

                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                ))


              : splitArray.slice(page, page + 2).map((item, index) => (
                  <li key={index} style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: '10px' }}>
                    <p>Semester {index + 1 + page}:</p>
                    <div className="semester-lines">
                      <div>
                      <p style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  {item
    .replace(/],/g, ']<br/>')
    .replace(/[[\]]/g, '')
    .split('<br/>')
    .map((line, index) => {
      const items = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
      const isEditable = items[1].toLowerCase().includes('elective') || items[1].toLowerCase().includes('cognate');

      return (
        <div key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
          <span style={{ padding: '5px', margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', maxWidth: '100px', height: 'auto' }}>
            {items[0]}
          </span>
          {isEditable ? (
            <input
              type="text"
              defaultValue={items[1]}
              style={{ height: 'auto', minHeight: '40px', overflow: 'hidden', resize: 'none', padding: '5px', maxWidth: '300px', margin: '5px', color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', textAlign: 'center' }}
              
              onChange={e => (items[1] = e.target.value)}
            />
          ) : (
            <span style={{height: 'auto',boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', padding: '5px', maxWidth: '300px', margin: '5px', backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)' }}>
              {items[1]}
            </span>
          )}
          <span style={{ padding: '5px', margin: '5px',  backgroundColor: '#323232', boxShadow: '6px 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30)', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
            {items[2]}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    })}
</p>


<button onClick={() => handleSave()}>
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
  </ul>
```

Comment: You should show the content of your handleSave function if you want us to help you. But already, I hope you know that items is a local variable so it will not be available outside your map callback function. So currently in your code it is not possible to know the data updated inside your handlesave function.